# Accessing Knockout Observable Property from Computed Property Gives TypeError

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm sure this is probably a basic problem, but I have the following ViewModel:

```
var viewModel = new EditorViewModel();
viewModel.addData(model);
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

var EditorViewModel = function () {

    var self = this;
    self.addData = function (data) { .
        ko.mapping.fromJS(data, {}, self);
    };
    self.isUpdate = ko.computed(function () { return self.id() !== "0"; }, self);

};
```

The ViewModel receives data via the `addData` method. This method then maps the received data using the Knockout Mapping Plugin. For info, this data is supplied via an external JQuery AJAX call.

The problem is that I am getting the following error in Mozilla:

`TypeError: self.Id is not a function`

I'm not sure why the computed property is causing this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, when you create a `ko.computed` it is immediately evaluated.

So in your case the `function () { return self.id() !== "0"; }` runs before you call your `addData` method, so your id property will be missing and you get the exception.

To fix this you need to tell KO to defer the evaluation with the [`deferEvaluation` option](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/computed-reference.html):

```
 self.isUpdate = ko.computed(
     function () { return self.id() !== "0"; }, 
     self, { deferEvaluation: true });
```

Comment: Thank you - I made the mistake of assuming `ko.computed` wasn't evaluated until `ko.applyBindings` was called.